# How to parse an xml (.aml file [Automation Markup Language]) which has recurring xml tags in java?

Tags: java, xml, recursion, xpath

I want to parse below xml. The catch is this xml is a very tiny portion of a very big file and the nested recurring InternalElement tag is not fixed i.e for some nodes there might be 3-4 levels , for some it is 10-15 levels. I tried using java xpath and used recursion if an InternalElement has a nested InternalElement , but my file size is +100MB and it affects the performance of the app.

```
<InstanceHierarchy Name="199190500_8EDAG1_273">
    <InternalElement Name="==199190500" ID="02FA9B0C-FA8C-46A9-B981-2A876C7F21C8">
        <InternalElement Name="=8EDAG1" ID="F506E2FE-4927-4F79-B8A4-FFB4CDED8CD9">
            <InternalElement Name="++ST000" ID="EF7AF96A-A8BD-434E-8683-5E86427B07E0">
                <InternalElement Name="+CE001" ID="87CF45F6-08FD-4CFA-89BA-D85F5DF7280A">
                    <InternalElement Name="-BE01" ID="CF3920C5-150B-4403-9D83-3695CFA0489C">
                        <InternalElement Name="JAN.1503351-359" ID="DE6104EA-DDBB-48E2-862B-AD201A4A1F15">
                            <InternalElement Name="ConnPoint&lt;#&gt;2" ID="49B50730-73F9-4A86-A0BE-8A6D04723FD6">
                                <RoleRequirements RefBaseRoleClassPath="EPLANRoleClassLib/Function"/>
                            </InternalElement>
                            <InternalElement Name="ConnPoint&lt;#&gt;2" ID="49B50730-73F9-4A86-A0BE-8A6D04723FD6">
                                <RoleRequirements RefBaseRoleClassPath="EPLANRoleClassLib/Function"/>
                            </InternalElement>
                        </InternalElement>
                    </InternalElement>
                    <InternalElement Name="-BE01" ID="CF3920C5-150B-4403-9D83-3695CFA0489C">
                        <InternalElement Name="JAN.1503351-359" ID="DE6104EA-DDBB-48E2-862B-AD201A4A1F15">
                            <InternalElement Name="ConnPoint&lt;#&gt;2" ID="49B50730-73F9-4A86-A0BE-8A6D04723FD6">
                                <RoleRequirements RefBaseRoleClassPath="EPLANRoleClassLib/Function"/>
                            </InternalElement>
                            <InternalElement Name="ConnPoint&lt;#&gt;2" ID="49B50730-73F9-4A86-A0BE-8A6D04723FD6">
                                <RoleRequirements RefBaseRoleClassPath="EPLANRoleClassLib/Function"/>
                            </InternalElement>
                        </InternalElement>
                    </InternalElement>
                </InternalElement>
            </InternalElement>
        </InternalElement>
    </InternalElement>
</InstanceHierarchy>
```

I tried using java xpath and used recursion if an InternalElement has a nested InternalElement , but my file size is +100MB and it affects the performance of the app.

Comment: "Parsing" the XML is trivial; it's processing the data once parsed that's difficult. But the way you process the data depends entirely on what you want to do with the data, which you haven't told us anything about. To progress this you should tell us (a) what output you are trying to achieve, (b) what you tried, and (c) how it failed. If the failure is slow performance, then give us some numbers.

Comment: Parsing a huge xml file will take time. If code is working I would figure another way of executing your code so it will not affect the performance.